# Extract url link with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to extract all links between **url** tags in the following content using `Regex`:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/rBHvpRWBkgyW99dXT88n7yEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/NX1NravqaXESu9fFv7KuqiEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/SKK6Nusyv8QPNMtI4j9J2yEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/gFXtEMCp1m_YzxsBpKl68iEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

It should returns a list of links:

- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/rBHvpRWBkgyW99dXT88n7yEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2
- https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/NX1NravqaXESu9fFv7KuqiEAvth_LlrfE80CYdSH47w.woff2

...

Thanks

Comment: `url\(([^()]+)\)` in capture group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `url\((.*?)\)`. This will capture everything starting from the opening parenthesis up to the first closing parenthesis. `.*?` means that the pattern will capture the minimum text that satisfies the pattern instead of all the text.

The captured URL will appear in the first capture group, eg :

```
var regex=new Regex(@"url\((.*?)\)");
var urls= ( from match in regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
            select match.Groups[1].Value
          ).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Or

```
var urls=regex.Matches(input)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(match=>match.Groups[1].Value)
              .Distinct()
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. How about there is a single quote to wrap url? Something like url:('..test/index.htm')? The quote is optional, may have or not!

Answer (score 2):

```
string content = "...";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"url\((https?://.+?)\)");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(content))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
var content = "..."; // your input here
var regex = new Regex("url\\((?<url>[^\\)]+)");
var urls = regex.Matches(content).Cast<Match>()
 .Select(m => m.Groups["url"].Value)
 .Distinct()
 .ToArray();
```

Regex explanation:

```
url // match "url" literaly
\( // match open brace
(?<url> // named capture group
[^\)]+ // match all chars until close brace
) // close capture group
```